# Нестрогий поиск по тегам в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица пользователей и справочник свойств (тегов) пользователей. Они относятся друг к другу как многие ко многим, т.е. существует третья промежуточная таблица с полями user_id, tag_id. Как организовать поиск похожих* пользователей?

**Похожими пользователями считаются те, у которого совпали наборы тегов. В идеале хотелось бы передавать параметром при поиске значение максимального расхождения состава/количества тегов.*

Можно делать все что угодно, по большому счету, даже использование Postgres`а не является обязательно. Но решение обязательно должно быть используемым NodeJS`ом.

Comment: подробнее опишите что такое "расхождение состава тегов". количество совпавших/отличающихся боле менее понятно, но вот "состав" ... И искать для конкретного пользователя похожих или просто всех похожих

Comment: Уточнить условия можно, но чем больше условий, тем меньше свободы. А задачка и так не тривиальная

Answer (score 1):

В общем виде запрос получающий подобие пользователей выглядит как то так:

```
select *
  from (
   select a.user_id a_user_id,b.user_id b_user_id,a.tcnt a_cnt,b.tcnt b_cnt,count(1) same_cnt
     from
       (select user_id,tag_id,count(1) over(partition by user_id) as tcnt
          from user_tags
         where user_id=NNN
       ) A,
       (select user_id,tag_id,count(1) over(partition by user_id) as tcnt
          from user_tags
       ) B
    where A.tag_id=B.tag_id and A.user_id!=B.user_id
    group by A.user_id,B.user_id,A.tcnt,B.tcnt
 ) T
 where a_cnt=b_cnt and same_cnt=a_cnt
```

В данном примере получаются все полностью одинаковые пользователи. Для поиска подобия надо исправить where в самом конце, исходя из того, что a_cnt - количество тегов у пользователя A, b_cnt - у пользователя B, same_cnt - количество совпадающих тегов. Если требуется искать подобие конкретного пользователя, то лучше всего добавить `where user_id=NNN`  внутрь подзапроса `A`.

Если же требуется действительно искать подобие всех пользователей всем пользователям, то запрос можно упростить, для ускорения работы:

```
with Q as(
 select user_id,tag_id,count(1) over(partition by user_id) as tcnt
   from user_tags
)
select a.user_id a_user_id,b.user_id b_user_id,a.tcnt a_cnt,b.tcnt b_cnt,count(1) same_cnt
  from Q a, Q b
 where a.tag_id=b.tag_id and b.user_id!=a.user_id
 group by a.user_id,b.user_id,a.tcnt,b.tcnt
having a.tcnt=b.tcnt and a.tcnt=count(1)
```

Comment: Нет, нужно найти всех подобных для конкретного пользователя

Comment: Мне кажется, или это довольно тяжелый запрос? Он мне не повесит БД на 100к пользователях и хотя бы 200 свойств?

Comment: @MiF Я в первый вариант запроса дописал пользователя. Конечно запрос тяжелый. Склейка по тегу должна хорошо по индексу отработать. Но подсчет количества тегов всех пользователей думаю основная проблема для производительности. Решается внесением например в таблицу пользователей уже посчитанного кол-ва тегов у него и ведение этого поля автоматом триггерами

Comment: @MiF Дальнейшую оптимизацию вижу в хранении данных по подобию и досчитыванию для новых пользователей и пользователе с меняющимися тегами

Comment: @MiF Если бы искать точное равенство то можно было бы посчитать некую контрольную сумму от тегов пользователя и тогда влет по ней находить.

Comment: @MiF И кстати у меня еще идея появилась ... вопрос в том, действительно ли у вас порядка 200 свойств или может быть много больше. И не помешала бы статистика по количеству уникальных наборов свойств у пользователей. многие теги часто встеречаются вместе от этого можно было бы отталкиватся, храня к пользователю id набора тегов и тогда подобие искать практически такими же запросами как выше, только по наборам свойств он быстро отработает, а потом вытянуть пользователей с этими наборами по id